# Chrome extension: ¿How to get href of button from class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I want a javascript to check if there is a button in the webpage that is being visited with the *class detail-w-button act_watchlink* like the following:

```
<a href="link" class="detail-w-button act_watchlink">
```

And if that button exists, I want to store in a variable the href.

How can I do this automatically when the page loads?

**Update:**
I don't know if it helps, but I know that the page has the following code to listen to the button:

```
$('.act_watchlink').on('click', function(){...});
```

I think it would be fine to just triggering that action automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check if a node exists with jQuery:

```
if($('a.detail-w-button.act_watchlink').length > 0)
    alert("I found it!");
else
    alert("There is no such button");
```

Get href of this button:

```
 var href = $('a.detail-w-button.act_watchlink').attr('href');
```

If you want to improve performance, store the button in a local variable instead of searching it each time you need it.

**Update:** If it is possible to encounter more than one such button on a page, you should address a specific item in the array of found objects. Like this:

```
var href = $('a.detail-w-button.act_watchlink').first().attr('href');
// note the first()

var href = $('a.detail-w-button.act_watchlink').eq(2).attr('href');
// note the eq(2)
```

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution to a question that is not tagged with jQuery is often not helpful. If the OP wanted a jQuery based solution, they could have/should have tagged the question with jQuery, or mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.act_watchlink').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Maybe a few words to explain which problem this solves?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution to a question that is not tagged with jQuery is often not helpful. If the OP wanted a jQuery based solution, they could have/should have tagged the question with jQuery, or mentioned it in the question.